# Ordering flex items in a flexbox

Tags: html, css

I wish to achieve the following:

[image]

```css
#box {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#spotLight img {
  width: 15%;
  height: 15%;
}

#spotLight h2 {
  flex: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

#spotLight p,
h3 {
  width: 20%;
  align-self: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <h2>Our product:</h2>
  <img src="productphoto.jpeg" />
  <h3>This product is in promotion!</h3>
  <p>
    description of product
  </p>
</div>
```

I'd like to arrange the flex items like in the picture. I can't get the `<p>description of product</p>` to sit right beneath the `<h3>This product is in promotion!</h3>`

Comment: if you want to use flexbox you need two addictional div one for the image e one for the text. You can also use grid to achieve this layout

Comment: Does it have to be this HTML structure, or could the h3 and p get put into an additional container element? You are trying to switch from row to column direction within the same flex container here, and that is not really possible, so you would have to “fake” the same effect some other way.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever used [the css gridbox?](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp) Using it would provide a very clean and easy to read solution to your problem. Here is a [js fiddle with the solution](https://jsfiddle.net/ZombieChowder/rvfbLa1w/10/) for your layout.

The important thing here is to notice how the `grid-template-areas` behaves in order to create the proper element layout. To achieve this layout, you just need 3 css properties inside your wrapper class:

```
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    'header header header header'
    'menu menu menu main'
    'menu menu menu right';
  grid-gap: 10px;
```

Checkout the link to the official documentation for gridbox I've provided and the fiddle with the solution for further explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I've added a wrapper around your text and changed your css selector from `#spotlight` to `#box`

```css
    #box {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      flex-direction: row;
      justify-content: center;
      justify-items: center;
      align-items: center;
    }

    #box img {
      width: 15%;
      height: 15%;
    }

    #box h2 {
      flex: 100%;
      text-align: center;
    }

    #box p,
    h3 {
      width: 20%;
      align-self: flex-start;
    }
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <h2>Our product:</h2>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" />
  <div class="wrapper">

    <h3>This product is in promotion!</h3>
    <p>
      description of product
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to keep the HTML structure and also have to use `flex`, you can still have a workaround using the trick of `margin-left: 50%`:

```css
#box {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

#box > * {
  border: solid 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  margin: 0;
}

#box h2 {
  flex: 100%;
}

#box img {
  flex: 0 1 50%;
  width: 50%;
}

#box h3,
#box p {
  flex: 1;
}

#box h3 {
  align-self: flex-start;
}

#box p {
  margin-left: -50%;
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <h2>Our product:</h2>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/640/480" />
  <h3>This product is in promotion!</h3>
  <p>description of product</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's play with flexbox in CSS. I hope, it helps you how to use flex.

```css
  @media(min-width:468px) {
  .container-1{
  display:flex;
  /* align-items:flex-start; */
  /* align-items:flex-end; */
  /* align-items:center; */
  /* flex-direction:column; */

  }
  .container-2{
    display:flex;
    /* justify-content:flex-start; */
    /* justify-content:flex-end; */
    /* justify-content:center; */
    justify-content:space-between;

  }
    }
    .container-3{
      display:flex;
      /* justify-content:flex-start; */
      /* justify-content:flex-end; */
      /* justify-content:center; */
      flex-wrap:wrap;
      justify-content:space-between;

    }
  .container-1 div, .container-2 div, .container-3 div{
    border:1px solid red;
    padding:10px;
  }
  .box-1{
  flex:2;
  order:3;
  }
  .box-2{
   flex:2;
   order:1;
  }
  .box-3{
  flex:1;
  order:2;
  }
  .box-container-2{
    /* width:27%; */
    flex-basis:30%;
  }
  .box-container-3{
    /* width:27%; */
    flex-basis:10%;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title> Flex </title>
</head> 

<body>
<div class="container-1">
  <div class="box-1">
    <h3>Box one</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box-2">
    <h3>Box two</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box-3">
    <h3>Box Three</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container-2">
  <div class="box-container-2">
    <h3>Box Four</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box-container-2">
    <h3>Box Five</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box-container-2">
    <h3>Box Six</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container-3">
  <div class="box-container-3">
    <h3>Box seven</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box-container-3">
    <h3>Box 8</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box-container-3">
    <h3>Box 9</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box-container-3">
    <h3>Box 10</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box-container-3">
    <h3>Box 11</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box-container-3">
    <h3>Box 12</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim.</p>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution is here:

```css
html {
  padding: 30px;
}

.bordered {
  border: 3px solid black;
}

.flexible {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

header {
  height: 50px;
  
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

section {
  order: 0;
}

section p {
margin: 0;
}

aside {
  order: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

aside .child {
  height: 150px;
  margin: 0 0 10px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <header class="flexible bordered">HEADER</header>
  <div class="wrapper">
  <section>
    <div class="image">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x320" alt="">
    </div>
  </section>
    <aside>
      <div class="child flexible bordered">Text</div>
      <div class="child flexible bordered">Text</div>
    </aside>
  </div>
</div>
```